# Heroku NodeJs Stuck in Build in Progress

Tags: node.js, heroku

I created a test-backend with NodeJs and tried to deploy it to Heroku.

I followed the instructions and the command git push heroku master was successful.

The app should have been deployed, but instead it is stuck in "Build in progress", as you see here:

[image: Stuck in build in progress]

The last lines shown in the build log are:

```
-----> Build
   Running build
   
   > test-backend@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_2dd56f0f
   > tsc -w
   
   c2:11:15 AM - Starting compilation in watch mode...
   
   
   2:11:19 AM - Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

It seems that Heroku is running my build script, I don't know why and why is it a problem.

My package.json scripts are as follow:

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev src/index.ts",
    "lint": "ts-standard",
    "build": "tsc -w",
    "start": "nodemon build/index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

Any idea of what is happening?

Comment: Heroku runs your build script by default. When deploying, you don’t want a build script that “watches” for file changes. Same with your start script. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my Build script in package.json and managed to deploy the NodeJs project to Heroku.